# PopupWindow showing only when finishing Activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display a PopupWindow on the top of my SurfaceView for 5 seconds when the user wins my game.
MainThread is used to handle the game loop.

With my code, when the game is won, it is paused for 5 seconds and the PopupWindow displays quickly when the activity finishes.
To be more accurate the PopupWindow is displayed on :

```
gActivity.finish();
```

instead on :

```
popupWindow.showAtLocation(this, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
```

What should I do ?

Here is my code :

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
  private MainThread thread;   // MainThread extends Thread

  ...

    if (gameWon) {

          thread.setRunning(false);
          thread.drawAndUpdate();
          popWellDoneWindow();

          Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
          returnIntent.putExtra("result", true);

          Activity gActivity = (Activity) (this.getContext());
          gActivity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
          gActivity.finish();
    }

  ...


  public void popWellDoneWindow() {

     LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)(getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
     ViewGroup popupView = (ViewGroup)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.well_done, null);

     PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH, Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT, false);
     popupWindow.showAtLocation(this, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);

     try {
         Thread.sleep(5000);
     }
     catch (InterruptedException ie){
         ie.printStackTrace();
     }
  }

}

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new GamePanel((GameActivity)this, (int) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("LevelNumber")));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/PopupWindow.java) for PopupWindow.java, it adds a View to the WindowManager.

When WindowManager#addView() is called, it isn't added synchronously; ie, the method can return before, while, or after the View is actually added. But it still does the add on the main thread. So the problematic code is

```
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

You're calling that right after calling a method that runs WindowManager#addView(), which means that method returns before the View has been added, and the current thread is stopped for 5 seconds, preventing it from actually being added.

Instead of `Thread.sleep()`, use a Handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ((Activity) GamePanel.this.getContext()).finish();
    }
}, 5000);
```

This will call the Activity's `finish()` method after 5 seconds, without blocking the main Thread.

Comment: @Moko if it works, would you mind "accepting" my answer so others can easily see that it did? There's a checkmark below the voting arrows.